# Defining the head of a list with a proof object

Tags: agda

I would like to define a `head` function for lists.
In order to avoid trying to compute the head of an empty list one
can either work with vectors of length greater than one (i.e., `Vec (suc n)`)
or work with `List`s, but pass a proof that the list is non-empty to `head`.
(This is what "Dependent Types at Work" calls *internal* vs *external*
programming logic, I believe.)
I am interested in the latter approach.
Note that there is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42288848/) which addresses this, but I wanted
a minimal approach. (For example, I would prefer not to use [Instance Arguments](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.1/language/instance-arguments.html)
unless they are required.)
Below is my attempt, but I don't fully understand what is going on.
For example:

1. It's not clear why I was able to skip the `head []` case. Obviously it's related to the "proof" I pass in but I would have expected I would need some kind of case with `()` in it.
2. When I type check (C-c C-l) I seem to get two goals as output.
3. I would have liked to have seen `tmp2` fail to type check.

Any insight would be very welcome.
In particular, what is the "right" way(s) to do what I am trying to do?

```
data List (A : Set) : Set where
    [] : List A
    _::_ : A → List A → List A

{-
head1 : {A : Set} → (as : List A) → A
-- As expected, complains about missing case `head1 []`.
head1 (a :: aa) = a
-}

data ⊤ : Set where
    tt : ⊤

data ⊥ : Set where

isNonEmpty : {A : Set} → List A → Set
isNonEmpty [] = ⊥
isNonEmpty (_ :: _) = ⊤

head : {A : Set} → (as : List A) → {isNonEmpty as} → A
head (a :: _) = a

-- Define just enough to do some examples

data Nat : Set where
    zero : Nat
    suc : Nat → Nat

{-# BUILTIN NATURAL Nat #-}

len1 : List Nat
len1 = 17 :: []

tmp : Nat
tmp = head len1

tmp1 : Nat
tmp1 = head len1 { tt }

len0 : List Nat
len0 = []

tmp2 : Nat
tmp2 = head len0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The user manual on [coverage checking in Agda](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.1/language/coverage-checking.html#matching-on-indexed-datatypes) explains that in certain situations absurd clauses can be left out completely:

> In many common cases, absurd clauses may be omitted as long as the remaining clauses reveal sufficient information to indicate what arguments to case split on. [...] Absurd clauses may be omitted if removing the corresponding internal nodes from the case tree does not result in other internal nodes becoming childless.

Note that you can still write the absurd clause manually if you want and Agda will accept it.

2. What you are getting are not two unsolved holes but two unsolved *metavariables*. These metavariables were created by Agda to fill in the implicit argument to `head` in the definitions of `tmp` and `tmp2` respectively, and Agda's constraint solver wasn't able to solve them. For the metavariable in `tmp`, this is because you defined `⊤` as a datatype instead of a record type, and Agda only applies eta-equality for record types. For the metavariable in `tmp2`, the type is `⊥` so there is no hope that Agda would be able to find a solution here.
3. When using Agda, you should see unsolved metavariables as a specific case of "failing to typecheck". They are not a *hard* type error because that would prevent you from continuing to use the interactive editing of Agda, and in many cases further filling in holes will actually solve the metavariables. However, they indicate "this program is not finished" just as much as an actual type error would.

Comment: Thank you. However, I now feel that the code I included in my question is not really a good way of doing what I was trying to do (namely the "external" approach of passing a proof as an extra parameter). I say this because of (2) and (3) in this answer. In addition, the answer I linked to (which uses Instance Arguments) works better than my code; i.e., there are no unresolved metavariables. In that example `tmp1` simply type checks, while `tmp2` generates a genuine error. Is there some reference that works out this (admittedly very simple) example in detail?

Comment: I don't think there's any fundamental difference here, just the facts that Agda uses a different resolution algorithm for instance arguments than for regular implicit arguments, and that an unsolved instance argument is actually a hard error if there are 0 candidates.